# Vue.js Scoped styling

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is more of a general question regarding the scoped styling of the SFC than a problem.

Let's say we have a child component that is just a wrapper for input element:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <input class="input" type="text" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}
</script>

<style scoped>
.input {
   width: 100%
   height: 40px;
}
</style>
```

In the parent component, we have a form where our input component is repeated:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <form>
         <div>
           <input-component />
         </div>
         <div>
           <input-component />
         </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import InputComponent from './InputComponent.vue'

  export default {
     components: { InputComponent }
  }
</script>
```

Since Vue.js auto generates additional class names for scoped styles, does this mean that the styles for both components are repeated each time the component is used with their own class or will it reuse the same style?

Comment: i think styles are usually extracted into css files so its reused, but it might differ based on how you package.